# iTextSharp returns a pdf that can not be opened

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, itext

I have followed the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp) and tried to output a pdf from an MVC view with iTextSharp to test the rendering fidelity.

I have the following code:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();

var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);

var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

document.Open();
var html = this.RenderView(GetViewName(), reportVM);
var css = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\Content\\site.css"));

var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(css));

var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html));

XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, msHtml, msCss);

document.Close();

return File(ms, "application/pdf");
```

Unfortunately it returns a window in the browser with the message:

> Failed to load PDF

What are the main causes of this behavior?

Note: I have produced a pdf from the same html with PdfSharp which is based on iTextSharp too, so I guess I am not using iTextSharp properly.

EDIT:

I have followed Bruno's suggestion in the comments, so I changed the return to :

```
 bytes = ms.ToArray();

 return File(new MemoryStream(bytes), "application/pdf");
```

And now the result is a 2 pages empty pdf, so it is better, but is it possible to make it more accurate, since the content of the pdf should have some text inside?

Comment: Have you tried opening the PDF in a text editor to see what it's contents are?

Comment: Why did you add this line: `writer.CloseStream = false;` The underlying `MemoryStream` is never closed! Also: the answer you refer to explicitly converts `ms` to an array: `ms.ToArray()`.

Comment: @DavidG, no, but thanks it is a good idea!

Comment: @meJustAndrew You should really listen to Bruno here, he works at iText so kinda knows what he's talking about...

Comment: Thank you @BrunoLowagie ,  it works without the `writer.CloseStream = false;` so it was my mistake indeed.

Comment: @DavidG , I found the fix, the pdf has been generated properly, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I saw the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438782/itextsharp-creates-pdf-with-blank-pages) and removed the `width` tags inside divs, and also ran an [online XHtml validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) to adjust everything else, I was able to generate a pdf relatively according to the coresponding HTML.